# How to download full Visual Studio 2017 Community with command line enabled?

Tags: backup, download, visual-studio-2017

I would like to download VS 2017 with command line enabled in installer because I am afraid MS will soon pull the plug out and I will be left with scenario "upgrade computer, buy new smartphone, etc".

So far I managed to download VS 2017 from non-MS site, GUI installer works, etc. The problem is, this is basically one time installation, and I would like to download all the files, makes a backup. And in order to download anything from MS I need new VS 2017 installer (to be able to work from command-line).

So I tried https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/ MS page with link to older version. This page requires me to log in into my account (I tried my two accounts), on one, I got nothing ("you have no benefits"), using my other account I got the links, but only two Professional version of VS 2017.

Does anyone has a trick in his/her sleeve how at the age of VS2019 get access to older Community version?

*Update: finally I got access to the Dev Essential program and I can see VS 2017 Community download button, but it seems the download itself is redirected in all cases to VS 2019. Those two links should give two different installers, but the effect is exactly the same:*

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15&src=myvs

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=community&rel=16

Comment: Even if you do end up installing it you still need a free license to actually use Visual Studio 2017 Community.  Are you sure VS2019 isn’t compatible with your project given that it’s an incremental build of VS2017.

Comment: @Ramhound, as for license it works for both accounts, I already checked, VS2017 runs fine. I simply don't know how to make a regular download, because MS put so many obstructions in the process. As for VS2017 itself, yes, I need it, basically I need frozen binaries of VS2017 as they are now, without any further/newer updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is to make an offline installation.

The Microsoft article
[Create an offline installation of Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)
has the answer.

You have already downloaded the Visual Studio Community Web installer
`vs_community.exe`.

Use this command line to create a local cache in the folder `c:\vslayout`
(or choose another folder):

```
vs_community.exe --layout c:\vslayout --includeOptional --lang en-US
```

Later on you could use this folder to install on this computer or another,
using the same options:

```
c:\vslayout\vs_community.exe --includeOptional
```

Note that `--includeOptional` will result in a huge download.
Use instead the `--add` parameter to help in limiting the size of the download
to just the components you need.
For that see
[Visual Studio workload and component IDs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-and-component-ids?view=vs-2019).

Older versions of Visual Studio can be downloaded from:

- Microsoft's own
  [Visual Studio Older Downloads - 2017, 2015 & Previous Versions](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/)
- By joining Microsoft's free
  [Visual Studio Dev Essentials](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/dev-essentials/).

Comment: Author doesn’t even have the installer to create the ISO

Comment: I already have read how to use the installer from command line, the problem is I am unable to download the installer in the first place (i.e. one with command line enabled). All I have is older installer with GUI only layer.

Comment: If you have the GUI installer `.exe`, then this is the installer you need. It has two modes of operation: GUI/Web and batch. Batch is triggered with the `--layout` parameter. If you don't have the right installer, try [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58091113/where-to-download-visual-studio-2017-community-edition-from).

Comment: I really wish the life is so easy. The old installer does not have the cmd-line enabled, and by MS advice from their forum I need the new (latest) 15.9 VS 2017 installer which works with cmd-line, however I am unable to download it.

Comment: Effectively Microsoft blocked that one. Try Microsoft's own [Visual Studio Older Downloads - 2017, 2015 & Previous Versions](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/). Or [this one](https://www.windowsmode.com/download-visual-studio-2017-for-windows/#Download_Visual_Studio_Community_2017_Offline_Installer_Links). Unfortunately, there are no ISO files for Visual Studio.

Comment: By the way, I joined the free [Visual Studio Dev Essentials](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/dev-essentials/) and the file is available: Visual Studio Community 2017 (version 15.9). Does it not support the `--layout` parameter?

Comment: Did you **check** the download? AFAIK despite the label/button says "2017", it is "2019". To check, click on .exe file, then properties, then details, the version should be 15.xx, if it is 16.xx it is 2019.

Comment: I have checked that the `.exe` name was different. But since you ask, the version is `15.9.28307.1033`.

Comment: Thank you, the other one indeed gives VS2017. Meanwhile I managed to target it as well (see the other answer), but the road was bumpy :-).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to download and install it. Here are my steps:

1. install nuget CLI from: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools
2. using nuget install chocolatey as package, more here: https://chocolatey.org/docs/installation#install-using-nugetexe-from-powershell
3. having chocolatey install VS2017 community package: https://chocolatey.org/packages/VisualStudio2017Community#files
4. when installing you can pay attention where the files are fetched from. When I am writing this, VS2017 is at: https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/57c99182-2828-4fc1-8b36-271e2472c838/91d7b8d8ba556b1e8723ca67a0f1e2e4a8274f7dfccbeae567e78b22f0db3f6d/vs_Community.exe
5. so either you download it directly, or switch to chocolatey cache directory (`%TEMP%\chocolatey`) and grab vs_community.exe
6. and then run the installer to fetch all the files needed to offline installation